# Generate custom RSS from a plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, rss

Using [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/) I was able to create basic custom RSS feed.

but I'd like to have a custom RSS generated from a plugin, and my Google-Fu failed me on that specific search. Is there any way to correctly generate custom feed from a plugin (and not "from" a template) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was sutpid of me not to have seen this, but I just have to follow the tutorial and not use get_template_parts()!

Moving on.